# Trigger click event on link tag in JS for Android and iPhone

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am developing mobile web application using Sencha Touch (JavaScript & ExtJS). I have a link tag (just `<a>` tag with `href`), and I need to trigger `click` event on it.
I have found that call of `myelement.dom.click();` do the job, but it's not working for Android... Is there some kind of universal solution?

UPDATE

I have a container with html code:

```
<a href="http://google.com" id="link_to_click" target="_blank">CLICK ME</a>
```

I need to simulate click on this link using only plain **JavaScript** and **ExtJS**. The link must be opened in new window/tab.

Comment: Describe your problem more. You are using which browser on Android device. Which android. Write here code which is not workin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `HTMLEvents` object with `document.createEvent()` to simulate a click on a link.

```js
var link = document.getElementById( 'link_to_click' ),
    event = document.createEvent( 'HTMLEvents' );

event.initEvent( 'click', true, true );
link.dispatchEvent( event );
```

Comment: this is genius, was searching for a solution to this for ages, cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

//android

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

//javascript

```
function bindIcons() {

            jQuery("a.icons").bind('mouseover mouseout mousedown mouseup focus blur touchstart touchend', function (e){
              if (typeof console !== "undefined" ) console.log(e);
              if (e.type=='mouseover' || e.type=='focus') 
              {
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('over',true);
              }

              if (e.type=='mousedown' || e.type=='touchstart') 
              {
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('down',true);
              }

              if (e.type=='mouseout' || e.type=='mouseup' || e.type=='touchend' || e.type=='blur') 
              {
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('down',false);
                jQuery(e.currentTarget).toggleClass('over',false);
              }
            });

            if (isAndroid())
               jQuery("a.ifandroid").attr("href","javascript:ifAndroid();");
            else
               jQuery("a.ifandroid").toggleClass('ifandroid',false);

      }
```

Comment: I am unable to use jQuery. All I can use is plain JavaScript and ExtJS. And this is event binding, but I need event triggering (click simulation).