# jQuery click trigger with touch devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a trigger click on page load, so am having a trigger function:

```
$("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(2).trigger('click');
```

It's working fine on Desktops, but it doesn't work with touch devices like Andriod and iPhones. I tried to add touchstart on the same click event:

```
$("li.vjs-menu-item").eq(2).trigger('touchstart click');
```

But it doesn't make any sense, so I want to know what is the equivalent trigger call for touch events ?

Comment: Do you have a `click` handler (e.g. `element.click(fn) or element.on('click', fn)`) on the `li`?

Comment: am having trigger click not element click @LeonAdler

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with pure javascript:

```
var link = document.getElementById( 'link_to_click' ),
    event = document.createEvent( 'HTMLEvents' );

event.initEvent( 'click', true, true );
link.dispatchEvent( event );
```

Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669335/4063816

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `touchend` event?
Also if that does not work you can try a work around by triggering `focusout`
event.